# Compile OpenEXR in cygwin

Tags: compiler-errors, cygwin, cross-compiling, openexr

I'm trying to compile OpenEXR with cygwin but i'm having troubles doing it.

What I've done so far:

```
cd ilmbase-X.X.X
./configure
make
make install
make check
```

I need this because it's OpenEXR needs it. It runs ok, and it creates in /usr/local three folders: `bin`, `include\OpenEXR` and `lib`.

Then I proceed to OpenEXR and this is what I do:

```
cd openexr-X.X.X
./configure
```

Everything runs ok but when I do `make` it gives me the following error:

```
b44ExpLogTable.cpp:52:18: half.h: No such file or directory
```

Although I'm not aware why does this happens I can work it around by doing this:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR
```

But then, when I hit `make` another error is thrown and I'm stucked in here:

```
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:511: undefined reference to `half::_toFloat'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:511: undefined reference to `half::_toFloat'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:481: undefined reference to `half::_eLut'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:511: undefined reference to `half::_toFloat'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:511: undefined reference to `half::_toFloat'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:481: undefined reference to `half::_eLut'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:499: undefined reference to `half::convert(int)'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:481: undefined reference to `half::_eLut'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:499: undefined reference to `half::convert(int)'
/usr/local/include/OpenEXR/half.h:499: undefined reference to `half::convert(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target `b44ExpLogTable' failed
make[1]: *** [b44ExpLogTable] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Andre/openexr-1.6.1/IlmImf'
Makefile:313: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Does this happens to anyone? I've googled a lot already and I can't find a solution. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is a bit old, but it helped me figure out the `-I` switch.

Once I got that, I figured out the answer to your problem. You're providing the include file, but not the library itself, hence the `undefined reference`. Use:

`./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/OpenEXR -L/usr/local/bin -lHalf-6"`

`-L` provides a library search directory, while `-l` provides a library to link into the program. `-lHalf-6` indicates the file `/usr/local/bin/cygHalf-6.dll`.

I couldn't tell you why the library is where it is, but it is.

You may also run into another problem with memset, which is solved here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/openexr-user/2011-07/msg00002.html

Comment: Thanks ;) I don't know why this happens, but it is solved now

Comment: Just a reminder to anyone else finding this, take special note of the file indicated here (cygHalf-6.dll).  This will likely be a different version number, so find the file and get the filename right.